# What is a glowstone impossible object?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-extra-utilities

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=stiEq0JlPzY) djh3max gets a new object that allows him to infinitely place blocks. At about 5:40 if you pause the video at the right time you can see that the object is called a "glowstone impossible object". I promptly googled this to find out what it was but I can't find a wiki page or any information at all. All I can ascertain is that it is from Extra Utilies. Does anyone know what this item is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "so, it's just that it's a sphere, and like you can place it down and stuff, but it doesn't actually do anything other than sit there and be spherical"
>
> "It lights up? That's about it."

[[source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/wip-mods/1443963-extra-utilities-v1-1-0k?page=132)]

You're correct about it being from Extra Utilities. It's basically a sphere that emits light. The name "Impossible Object" is a reference to the fact that true spheres are impossible in Minecraft.

Below is an example of a player using Impossible Objects as ornaments for a Christmas tree.

[image]

Comment: So it doesn't actually do anything, it's just a sphere? I have been deceived!

Comment: As far as I know of, that's correct. I might just end up trying it myself. :p